# How to get multiple html controls to use the same event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have some javascript and am creating some html on the fly. What I want to do is add an event handler to each control (they are all “Input” controls) so that if I click on any of them they all fire the same event. I first define a delegate in the initialize section of the code like this:

```
 this.rule_event_handler = Function.createDelegate(this, this.rule_selected);
```

I have a function shown below that I want all the controls to call when clicked:

```
 rule_selected: function () {}
```

I add the handler as shown below:

```
display_rules: function () {
    var rulearea = $('#ruleControlArea')[0];
    rulearea.innerHTML = "";
    for (intI = 0; intI < this.arrRules.length; intI++) {
        rulearea.innerHTML += this.create_rule_control(intI, this.arrRules[intI].display);
        $addHandlers($('#rule_' + intI)[0], { 'click': this.rule_event_handler }, this, true);
    }
},
```

The problem I then see is that only the last control cause the onclick event to fire. How can I change the code so that all the controls will fire the same event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the .live method

```
rule_selected: function () {}
```

add a class `selectable` to your rules and add the live event before creating/deleting your rules items

```
$(".selectable").live("click", rule-selected);
```

If you really want to use the id of your rules, i'd look into your usage of ids; it looks like you're using the same id many times on the page (you're using the id query as an array, which i find strange; any specific reason for that?) and that may cause weird behavior.

EDIT

here is a sample

```
<div id="RulesControlArea">
</div>

<div id="AddRule">Add Rule</div>
<div id="DisplayRules">Display Rules</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function display_rules() {
        var rulearea = $('#RulesControlArea');
        rulearea.empty();
        for (intI = 0; intI < 10; intI++) {
            rulearea.append("<div id='" + Math.random() + "." + intI + "' class='selectable'>this is a rule from display_rules</div>");
        }
    }

    $("#RulesControlArea .selectable").live('click', function(element) { alert(element.target.innerHTML); });
    $("#AddRule").click(function() { $("#RulesControlArea").append("<div id='" + Math.random() + "' class='selectable'>this is a rule</div>"); });
    $("#DisplayRules").click(display_rules);
</script>
```

Comment: you may want to follow the advice given to me in this answer, and use the module pattern by wrapping the whole call in a jQuery start function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709950/how-to-use-javascript-namespaces-correctly-in-a-view-partialview